# Parse Server: Custom endpoint / Express route

Tags: node.js, express, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

In Parse Server, where should you put express routes? I found they only work if I put them straight in index.js, but that can't be the best place, is it?

I put this in my cloud/main.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen();

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log("working?");
    res.status(200).send('working?');
});

console.log("this file definitely runs");
```

My console output shows "this file definitely runs" on starting the server, but when I try to access localhost:1337/test, it just says "Cannot GET /test". Whereas if I put just the app.get('/test', ...); in index.js, it works. I suppose it's because I'm not allowed to create another express() instance, maybe there's a way to get the instance that was created in index.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realise you are asking a different question than what my answer is pointing to. In case you still actually forgot the `app.listen` I'll leave it below.

If you're going to export your routes to a different file you'll need to pass around the `app` object from your `index.js` to the routes file.

What I usually do is three levels of abstraction. Firstly, you have the `index.js` which declares the `app` and `express instances`. Then I have a seperate file, say `routeDefinitions.js`(I usually call this index and name the starting point after my application).

Inside `routeDefinitions.js` I declare the routes using the `app` instance from `index.js` resulting in the following:

`app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var routes = require('./routeDefinitions')(app);
```

and `routeDefinitions.js`:

```
var test = require('./test');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/test', test.working);

    return app;
};
```

And then have each type of object in it's own route file (say you have users, apples and cars then each of those objects has it's own routes file).

`test.js`:

```
module.exports.working = function(req, res) {
    console.log("working?");
    res.status(200).send('working?');
};
```

---

You need to start your server by calling `app.listen` See the [Hello World example](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html).

You see `This definitely runs` because you are indeed processing your script, however you are not listening to requests because you forgot to start your express server.

Comment: thanks, I'll give that a try!

Even after adding app.listen(), it's not working. The reason I added "this definitely runs" is because sometimes node.js silently stops including files if there are errors, so I wanted to make sure it's loading the whole file

Comment: Gah, it failed, but I think that's because of Parse Server. Here's the error:

http://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/zwo

Comment: It does indeed looks to be a problem in the Parse Server. I don't have any experience with parse-server. I don't see any clear errors. Since it seems you're using the example project I'd suggest getting a clean install, configuring it with only the necessery options and once that works start moving stuff around, making sure everything keeps working with each and every change.

Comment: I actually needed to start up a new project and went with above architecture. I found the bug and edited the answer, specifically I removed the `app.use(routes);` line and appended `(app)` to `var routes = require('./routeDefinitions')`. It should work now.

Comment: wow, thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for :) it's working now!